# In PostgreSQL, how to INSERT INTO and use destination table's autoincrement column

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Suppose you have two tables in PostgreSQL. Table **A** has field **x**, which is of type **character varying** and has a lot of duplicates. Table **B** has fields **y**, **z**, and **w**. **y** is a **serial** column, **z** has the same type as **x**, and **w** is an integer.

If I issue this query:

```
INSERT INTO B
SELECT DISTINCT ______, A.x, COUNT(A.x)
FROM A
WHERE x IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY x;
```

I get an error regardless of what I have in `______`. I've even gotten as exotic as `CAST(NULL as INTEGER)`, but that just gives me this error:

> a null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allowed and even encouraged to specify your columns when using INSERT (and you really should **always** specify the columns):

```
insert into b (z, w)
select x, count(x)
from a
where x is not null
group by x
```

And I don't see the point of `distinct` when you're already grouping by `x` so I dropped that; I also dropped the column prefixes since they aren't needed and just add noise to the SQL.

If you don't specify a column when using INSERT, you get the default value and that will give you the sequence value that you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. That was it! And thanks for the reminder about specifying columns.

I agree about column prefixes. Only added them here for clarity.